# Error in declaring default parameters for method

Tags: c#, function, methods, default-parameters

I am using default parameters but I'm getting error

> Default parameter value for 'regularExpression' must be a compile time
>   constant

Here is the **method** signature:

```
public static PIPE.DataTypes.BuyFlow.Entities.Question GetEmailAddressQuestion(string regularExpression = RegularExpressions.EmailAddressRegex, int rank = 1, bool isRequired = true)
{
}
```

And here is the property:

```
public static string EmailAddressRegex
{
    get {
            string emailAddressRegex = @"^[A-Za-z0-9\._%\+\-]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,40}\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)$";
            return emailAddressRegex;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is like the error message says. Default parameters have to be constants (at compile time).

The Getter of `EmailAddressRegex` could return different values during runtime. That this is always the same value is not known to the compiler.

So change the `EmailAddressRegex` to a `const string` than the compiler error will be gone.

E.g.

```
public const string EmailAddressRegex = @"^[A-Za-z0-9\._%\+\-]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,40}\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)$";
```

Answer (score 1):

Default values for optional parameters are required to be compile-time constants.

In your case, a workaround would be:

```
public const string EmailAddressRegex = @"^[A-Za-z0-9\._%\+\-]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,40}\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)$";
```

Here more details .. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: @Steve .... yes .... i missed it .. thanks for acknowledging